# Ansible Tower variable for SCM commit ID/SHA

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm using a source controlled project in Ansible Tower that plugs into github/azure devops.

I'm looking for (but can't find) a variable that represents the commit ID/SHA hash of the playbook.yml im running, so I can log it to a built VM im building with it and go back and audit it later.

Answer (score -2):

`$(Build.SourceVersion)` will have the commit ID. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)